# How to organising your code in Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, package, project-organization

How do I organise my code? I have tried to put everything in a different package but then my notifications with GCM doesn't work anymore. if i put everything in the same root package no problem.

this are my two tests, left gives problems on gcm right doesn't:

[image]

Is there any way to easy organise your code like I did in the right one? or do all the classes, activities, services needs to be in the same package?

**EDIT 1 = SOLUTION**

You need to create your own class that extends GCMBroadcastReceiver like this:

```
import android.content.Context;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver;

public class GCMReceiver extends GCMBroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    protected String getGCMIntentServiceClassName(Context context) {
        return "yourAppPackage.yourNewAddedPackage.GCMIntentService";
    }
}
```

Then you need to change the default receiver in your manifest to the package where this class is located. for example:

```
<receiver android:name="yourPackage.PackageOfTheGCMReceiver.GCMReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="be.vanlooverenkoen.piautomation" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create your own class that extends GCMBroadcastReceiver like this:

```
import android.content.Context;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver;

public class GCMReceiver extends GCMBroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    protected String getGCMIntentServiceClassName(Context context) {
        return "yourAppPackage.yourNewAddedPackage.GCMIntentService";
    }
}
```

Then you need to change the default receiver in your manifest to the package where this class is located. for example:

```
<receiver android:name="yourPackage.PackageOfTheGCMReceiver.GCMReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="be.vanlooverenkoen.piautomation" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to organize your code, you have patterns options like: MVC, There is a great debate about whether Android uses default MVC.

But I see your picture in your structure you want a recommendation for .java files.
I give the following recommendation that I have seen in different files, books and github repositories (The packages are in alphabetical order):

activities

adapters

authenticator

data

data.migrations

fragments

helpers

interfaces

models

preferences

sync

Comment: aah ja oke, yea that is what I am trying to do, but the problem is with my GCM can't receive any messages anymore

Comment: i figured out that the GCMIntentService needed to be in my root, but all the rest can stay in packages. is there a way to change this?

Comment: Sometimes create a package with services, but i dont see constantly